# Bootstrap dropdown menu suddenly stopped working after adding ajaxToolkit:SlideShowExtender

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, slideshow

Well, as the title said, my problem is that after add ajaxToolkit:SlideShowExtender to my Main.aspx, that page's Bootstrap dropdown menu stop working, and when i go to other page, drop down menu comeback to life itself. If i remove ajaxToolkit:SlideShowExtender from my Main.aspx, the Bootstrap dropdown menu begin to work again. So how can i put these 2 together?
I put my dropdown menu to my master page and all other pages is using that master page. Everything work fine unless i add ajaxToolkit:SlideShowExtender.
I also put these scripts on the head of the master page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And these are the drop down menu code in the master page.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="Main.aspx">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="Item.aspx">Item</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Account<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="Log_In.aspx" id="logIn" runat="server">Log in</a></li>
                <li><a href="Register.aspx" id="registration" runat="server">Registration</a></li>
                <li><a href="Default.aspx" id="logOut" runat="server">Log out</a></li>
                <li><a href="Modify.aspx" id="modify" runat="server">Modify</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Orders<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="Cart.aspx">Cart</a></li>
                  <li><a href="History.aspx">History</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li id="adminControl" runat="server" visible="false" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Admins<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="Item_Control.aspx">Item management</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Order.aspx">Order managerment</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Article.aspx">Article managerment</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Search.aspx">Search</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div> <!--/container -->
</div> <!--/navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top -->
```

Than you all for reading this question and for all your help.

Comment: Note 1: Look like i only have this problem when used SlideShowExtender, when i used other tool, everything is fine.